# roslibjs MultiArray Message

Tags: ros, multiarray, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to create a web interface for a robot, and would like to publish a message of type:

```
std_msgs/Int32MultiArray
```

Thus in my code I have the following statement to create the message:

```
var msg = new ROSLIB.Message({
  data : [1 , 2, 3]
});
```

However, when I attempt to publish that in my browser I see a Javascript error of type 'cannot read property of undefined.'

I suspect it has to do with the way I am trying to set the message data, but cannot find an example of the proper way to do so. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209222/roslibjs-multiarray-message/) by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on ROS Answers with karma: 593 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear aak2166,
I used roslibjs for publishing a geometry_msgs/PoseArray and it seems to work

This the code used:

```
var pose = new ROSLIB.Message({
                    position : {
                      x : 0.1,
                      y : 0.2,
                      z : 0.2
                    },
                    orientation : {
                      x : 0.0,
                      y : 0.0,
                      z : 0.0,
                      w : 1.0
                    }
        
                  });
    
var pose_array = new ROSLIB.Message({
            poses : [pose, pose]    
              });

var pose_array_topic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
        ros : ros,
        name : '/test_pose_array',
        messageType : 'geometry_msgs/PoseArray'
          });

pose_array_topic.publish(pose_array);
```

---

Originally posted by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) with karma: 133 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0